# I want to show the asterisk if a particular option in the dropdown is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

Sorry for not being clear earlier. Uhm what I wanted is to display an asterisk to a particular  text if a particular option in a drop down menu is selected. Like it to say its a required field like that. I'm really really new in web development so I really need some help guys.

I need to change it to display inline and visibility visible when i click a button.

This is my html tag:

`font color=red id="dobRec" style="display:none;visibility:hidden;">* /font>`

My JQuery code is this:

```
<script>
        $("#custType").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val == 'R') {
                //display the asterisk
            }elseif ($(this).val == 'B') {
                //do something here

            }
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: `<font>` tags are deprecated. You should use `<span>` and CSS attributes to customize your styles.

Answer (score 4):

## Welcome to web development :)

It would be helpful to see the any code that you may have already.  Could you paste some in for us?

#### Changing Styles With jQuery

I am going to need to make some assumptions without seeing your code, but changing css attributes such as visibility using jQuery can be done as follows:

```
$('#idOfTag').css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

You can get more information at http://api.jquery.com/css/

It is worth noting that you can also define complete JS Objects containing multiple css attributes you wish to change and applying them all at once.

```
var cssStyle = {
       'visibility':'visible',
       'width':'190px',
       'float':'left'
        }

$('#idOfTag').css(cssStyle);
```

Note that there is not a comma after the last attribute.  This is required for correct JavaScript syntax.

#### Button Binding

You can bind events to the click of a button by doing the following:

```
$('#idOfButton').bind('click', function(e) {
      //If you don't want the default action to occur you can do
      e.preventDefault();

      //Here, the 'this' object refers to the button
      //You can execute the previous code to change the css of the other element here
});
```

There are other ways to accomplish this, some less verbose (I personally prefer this verbose way) such as

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function(e) {

});
```

This does the same thing.  Its up to you
I hope this answers your question.  Let me know if there is anything else I can help with.

More information along with some other cool css stuff you can do with jQuery can be found on my blog post at http://benashby.com/jquery/changing-css-attributes.

Comment: thanks, I guess I was not clear here hehe. Uhm what I really wanted was I need to display the asterisk if a particular option in the dropdown is selected.

Comment: Ahhh, well that's an entirely different can of worms.  You can bind() on the <select> tag to execute a function in which you can check the val() of $(this) and see if it equals the flagged value in which case you can make execute the css changing jQuery code.  I'll see if I can throw together a blog post real quick that might help to better explain this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.css()` in jQuery

```
$('#dobRec').css({
    "display" : "inline",
    "visibility":"visible"
});
```

EDIT : Since the question has changed - you were almost there use `.val()` with the braces

```
$("#custType").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'R') {
           //display the asterisk
        } elseif ($(this).val() == 'B') {
            //do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: actually i am using a dropdown menu not button. What i really want is to make the asterisk appear whenever i select the option whose id =R uhm this is my jquery code:
 <script>
        $("#custType").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val == 'R') {
                show dobRec
            }
            else {
               //do something here
            }
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

Three solutions are possible:

1) 
Create a css class myStyle:

```
 .myStyle{
         display:inline;
         visibility: visible;

  }
```

and add it to your element ,it can be done using **addClass()** like this :

```
   $('#dobRec').addClass('myStyle');
```

2)you can also use **css()** of jQuery:

```
   $('#dobRec').css({  "display" : "inline",  "visibility":"visible"});
```

3)An other solution is to edit your Style attribute using **Attr()** Like this :

```
   $('#dobRec').attr('style','display:inline;visibility:visible');
```

So the full solution after your edit :

```
    $("#custType").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'R') {
            $('#dobRec').css({
                   "display" : "inline",
                   "visibility":"visible"
            });

        }else if ($(this).val() == 'B') {
            //do something here

        }
    });
```

**Here is jsfiddle solution of what you want :**  http://jsfiddle.net/HteKD/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Uhm actually I am using a drop down. And whenever i choose the option in the dropdown whose id = 'R' I need to show the asterisk. Like if this is selected I need to show the asterisk to mark it is a required field like that.

Comment: <script>
        $("#custType").change(function(){
            if ($(this).val == 'R') {
                //show the asterisk
            }
            else {
               //do something here
            }
        });
    </script>

Comment: i added a jsfiddle solution